# How to set route parameter in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I have this view method witch required 2 arguments

```
[Route("chatbot/{chatbotId}/intents/{intentId}")]
public IActionResult Intents(int chatbotId, int intentId)
{
    return View();
}
```

The question is how can I pass the argument from ASP.NET Core core to it?

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" 
      asp-controller="Chatbot" asp-action="Intents">Intents</a>
```

Comment: `asp-route-chatbotId="..."` etc?

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOT.... this is amazing, I didnt know i could simply do this. wow thank you, i really didnt know you could build arguments like this. But yeah this is defintily what I was looking for Thank you. If you want to answer it i will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use **"asp-all-route-data"**. So you can name your route like the following:

```
[Route("chatbot/intents/", Name="intents")]
public IActionResult Intents(int chatbotId, int intentId)
{
    return View();
}
```

And in the .cshtml file:

```
@{
var parms = new Dictionary<string, int>
            {
                { "chatbotId", 1 },
                { "intentId", 1 }
            };
}

<a asp-route="intents"
   asp-all-route-data="parms">Intents</a>
```

For more help, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0) link.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,If you want to use  `asp-route-xxx` as `Jeremy Lakeman` said,you need to change your Route like this:

```
[Route("chatbot/intents")]
```

And `<a>` link can be like this:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Chatbot" asp-action="Intents" asp-route-chatbotId="1" asp-route-intentId="2">Intents</a>
```

If you change your route like `chatbot/intents`,it means chatbotId or intentId is not required in the route.

If you don't want to change Route `[Route("chatbot/{chatbotId}/intents/{intentId}")]`.You can use href to replace taghelper(I use fake data,1 as chatbotId,2 as intentId in the example):

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Chatbot/1/Intents/2">Intents</a>
```